# Test run in a global variable

Tags: global-variables

"Implement your algorithm in Java. Provide the argument for the test run in a global variable."
What does it mean to provide the argument for the test run in a global variable?

Comment: You can provide the input arguments of a program in various ways: through the keyboard, in a file, as command line arguments, or in a global variable (and there are probably a few more examples). If it's through the keyboard, for example, then it is actually the user of your program who passes the input. If it's through a global variable, then it is typically whoever has access to your code (which could be either you or the person to which you submit this exercise I suppose).

Comment: @barakmanos In my case I have a method that has to be tested. In which way can I provide a global variable? Is maybe a person who will test it that can modify its parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your program should look **more or less** like this:

```
public class Test
{
    private static final int INPUT_ARG = ...;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You can provide input arguments to a program in various ways:

- Inside an input file.
- Through the keyboard.
- As command-line arguments.
- Hard-coded within your program.

In this case, you are asked to use the last option mentioned above, and hard-code the input argument as a global variable within your code. In all other options, the user of your program can change the input arguments without having to rebuild the program. But in the latter case, only those who have access to the source code of your program can change the input arguments.